# Making dynamic ajax requests in Python

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

This might sound like a stupid question, but i am stuck at this step and badly need help. So I am trying to scrape this page [here][1] . This page makes a AJAX requests, whose header is as follows:

```
{
:authority: www.trip.com
:method: POST
:path: /restapi/soa2/16709/json/rateplan?testab=f14a7b98f0e497fd586c2946707d076a563a3d1d457219aa731e1cc518fe9df2
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 1661
content-type: application/json
}
```

In this header for the key **"path"** , the value of **"testab"** is generated dynamically. Now i want to get that value using only request method and not by opening the browser. So when i navigate to this url using request module, I want to be able to capture the value of **"testab"** dynamically. It would be a great help if anyone can provide me a solution. Thanks in advance. Also i cannot use scrapy for this purpose.

[1]: https://www.trip.com/hotels/mumbai-hotel-detail-762871/grand-hyatt-mumbai/?checkIn=2020-09-14&checkOut=2020-09-15&cityId=724&adult=2&children=0&ages=&crn=1&travelpurpose=0&curr=USD&showtotalamt=0&hoteluniquekey=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPaycjFK8Fk8B8GGIWYOBilFjNyfJl7U12Iy9DE0sTczNzQwMhgCrNFs44jAwgcaHDwBDMKWh0CeCYxSnKCeef3OAiC6AbVnQ5OrBxr_SRYZjB-P663gpFxIyNEY5LDDkamE4x-C5j-PnnDvIuJleM1uwTTISA9SVCC5RQTwyUmhltMDI-YGF4xMXxiYvgFVdHEzNDFzDCJGaJuFjPDImYGIRaQG6UUjMxTjI0NE00tzYzMTSwT00B0qplJYpKxUXKiuaW5ArdG16GPv1iNGKyYpRjdPBiD2Iwd3SyMXKJkuJg9_YIE4xpqS16d2m4vxRwa7KKoqyj_JSdM2iGJNTVPNyIi4x1LAWMXI5MA4yRGTo7m3U8-Mp5gTAYA1R43aDgBAAA(

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup to scrape the variables you are looking for, and then use them for your requests.

Answer (score 1):

to accomplish this you can use `curl`

use pip and do `pip install pycurl`

then your code would look something like this (I copied code from documentation)

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.io/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
# Body is a string in some encoding.
# In Python 2, we can print it without knowing what the encoding is.
print(body)
```

[documentation here](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html)

However I recommend using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) because doing a request will merely get you the html and not load dynamic content, then you'd also have to find how to parse the data.